# Make a Confirmation Modal using React & Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, modal-dialog

I was making an application in which I need to make a **confirmation box** to ask the user if he wants to delete the record or not. I want to use the **confirmation box globally**.

Suppose I want to delete a record, when the user clicks the delete button it executes the action to delete the record.
But once inside the delete action another action is dispatched to show Modal. (till this point I have reached)
However, I'm struggling on the part where execution should wait for the user to click confirm or cancel.
Once the user has performed the action then execution to delete the record should continue.

I hope my problem statement was clear.

Please let me know what should I do. I really want to learn how this thing works in React.

Currently, I'm using a window's confirmation to ask the user Yes or No.

```
// Delete Profile
export const deleteProfile = (history) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        if (
            window.confirm('Are you Sure? Your account would be permanently lost')
        ) {
            await axios.delete(`/api/profile`);

            dispatch({ type: actionTypes.CLEAR_PROFILE });
            dispatch({ type: actionTypes.ACCOUNT_DELETED });
            history.push('/login');
            dispatch(
                setAlert('Your account has been deleted permanently', 'success')
            );
        }
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch(setAlert('Profile deletion error', 'danger'));
    }
};
```

I'm hoping to call a modal in place of window confirmation and wait for user input, if it returns true I want to move ahead or else abort.

Comment: Can you put an example of the code you are talking of? It will be good see how you are handling the action and the dispatcher.

Comment: Hi Paul, I have added the piece of code of action file. I'll also update what I've been trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a Component called Dialog that opens when the deleteProfile method is called and put two buttons, one for canceling and the other for delete, when the delete button is pressed you call the deleting code. I recommend you to use some library like [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/). This library has multiple useful and very good looking components that you can utilize. For this case in specific I recommend you the [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#dialog) component. You can use it like this:

```
<Dialog
   open={dialogOpen}
   onClose={dialogClose}
   >
   <DialogContent>
      Are you Sure? Your account would be permanently lost
   </DialogContent>
   <DialogActions>
      <Button>Cancel</Button>
      <Button onClick={deleteMethod}>Delete</Button>
   </DialogActions>
</Dialog>
```

Where `dialogOpen` is either a boolean component state or a redux state when is true, the Dialog will open; and `dialogClose` is a method where you will change the `dialogOpen` state to false to the Dialog to close.

Now as you can check you have the `deleteMethod` where all you deleting code will be. You call this code when the delete button is pressed.

For open the Dialog asynchronusly what you can do is put and await once you set `dialogOpen` variable, something like this:

```
await this.setState({dialogOpen: true});
```

or if you want inside an async method like this:

```
const method = async () =>{
  await this.setState({dialogOpen: true});
}
```

And you just have to call the method like this:

```
await method();
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to call this component asynchronously and wait for user Input.

Comment: As per my understanding, I will dispatch an action named SET_DIALOG which will change the state of  ***isSetDialog*** to true. This will cause the Dialog to be visible and then we can wait for the user's input.

Comment: How can I dispatch an action asynchronously that will trigger the isSetDialog and also wait for the user's input?

Comment: You have to set the variable of `isSetDialgo` asynchronulsy. I have edited my answer with an example

Comment: Thank you so much Paul for your help. I'll try to implement what you have suggested.

Comment: No problem :) I hope it helps. If it helps can you mark the response as the answer please

Comment: Hey Paul, I got the time to implement your solution. However, it didn't work out for me. I tried different method and it worked out for me. I'll soon post the solution. Again Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry :( I'm glad that you found the solution :) I look forward to see how you solved it! Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Open confirmation box on click of delete button.
Delete record on click of confirm button.